# Why do some Linux files have a 'd' suffix?

Tags: filenames, terminology

I observed some of the binary files and configuration filenames end with a `d`.
What is reason for putting a `d` at the end of the file name?

Like `httpd`, `ospfd`, `pppd`, `syslogd`, `telnetd`, `pptpd`, `inetd`, `bootlogd` and `dhcpd`.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

They are [daemons (Computing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29) – as in "*workers behind the curtain*".

```
http   Daemon - Hypertext Transfer Protocol Daemon
ospf   Daemon - Open Shortest Path First Daemon (89)
ppp    Daemon - Point-to-Point Protocol Daemon
syslog Daemon - Syslog Daemon
telnet Daemon - Telnet server Daemon
pptp   Daemon - Point-to-Point Tunneling Protocol Daemon
dhcp   Daemon - Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol Daemon
```

All depending on how you interpret the word they can definitively also be
demons.

As [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29#Terminology) and *[Take Our Word For It](http://www.takeourword.com/TOW146/page4.html)* explains; the words is taken from [Maxwell's daemon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_demon)

[image: Courtesy of Htkym Creative Commons]

<sub>[Maxwell's_demon.svg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Maxwell%27s_demon.svg) Htkym [CC](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/deed.en), Wikipedia</sub>

– *"an imaginary agent which helped sort molecules of different speeds and worked tirelessly in the background."*

---

Else the usage of the word is somewhat in these lines:

```
daemon: spirit      (polytheistic context)
demon : evil spirit (monotheistic context)
```

---

***Fix#1:***

And as pointed out by the good Mr. [@Michael Kjörling](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/2465/michael-kjorling), to emphasize: 
*"Of course, just because the executable's name ends in `d` doesn't mean it is a daemon."*

```
sed    Stream Editor
dd     Data Description 
chmod  Change file mode bits 
xxd    Hex Dump
find   Find
```

etc. are examples of frequently used  tools ending in `d`. Then again that would
not be an added suffix as in `sedd`.

```
ls /usr/bin/*d /bin/*d
```

Though; typically daemons have the letter `d` appended at the end.

`telnet` vs `telnetd`

Another [writeup](http://www.linfo.org/daemon.html) on the subject of *Nix Daemons.

Comment: Of course, just because the executable's name ends in `d` doesn't mean it *is* a daemon. See `ls /usr/bin/*d` for examples.

Comment: `find` - the daemon with fins...

Comment: Also: *Disk And Execution MONitor*.

Comment: Oh my God! I'd have never guessed that it was taken from Maxwell's daemon!

Comment: Sounds like you made an [UUOC](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html) with `ls | cat`. You can use the one-line option: `ls -1`.

Comment: `ld` - linker daemon; `pwd` - print whereabouts daemon; `head` - hold everything after (so many lines) daemon; `find` - flatten inscrutable nesting daemon.

Comment: @TobiasKienzler: Ah. Always thought that was Linus Torvalds evil twin. Also a Fin.

Comment: @Sukminder :-D That's what that daemonic dolphin wanted you to believe

Comment: @TobiasKienzler: lol, This actually is starting to mold into some fine ideas for a good *geek short story*.

Comment: Oh god, what have I done? Wait, what letter did that deity end with?!

Comment: `id` - I daemon.

Comment: Linguistically, daemons and demons are the same thing and renderings of the same word. ‘Dæmon’ is the Greek word for a minor deity. After christianity started using Greek, the word got repurposed to mean evil pagan deities, and then just lost all non-negative connotations and eventually got simplified to demon. It's still the same word in German, though: Dämon (Daemon).

Comment: Instead of "They're", i'd put "Most are" ;)

Answer (score 11):

They're [daemons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29). Simple as that.

Comment: instead of "They're", i'd put "Most are" ;)

Comment: Fair comment @OlivierDulac, but the ones he explicitly listed all actually are.